# TYPO3 scheduler doesn't schedule?

Tags: typo3, fastcgi, scheduler

I've installed a TYPO3 schedule but it doesn't schedule. I've setup a cron job every 5 minutes to run TYPO3 scheduler and in my syslog it prints me the line:

> Oct  6 14:00:01 server /USR/SBIN/CRON[31775]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler)

hence I think the cron job is working but in my TYPO3 backend I can't see the schedule. It seems that TYPO3 script isn't started properly. When I run `cli_dispatch.phpsh` from the shell it gives me many strange errors. The script has every user permissions needed. Thanks for any help!

When I start from terminal with sh cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler it gives:

```
sh cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler 
cli_dispatch.phpsh: line 2: ?php: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cli_dispatch.phpsh: line 3: /120120.tgz: Keine Berechtigung
cli_dispatch.phpsh: line 4: ajax.php: command not found
cli_dispatch.phpsh: line 5: ajax.php: command not found
cli_dispatch.phpsh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `c'
cli_dispatch.phpsh: line 6: `*  (c) 2005-2008 Kasper Skaarhoj (kasperYYYY@typo3.com)'
```

Does it work at all with fastcgi enabled?

When I start cli_dispatcher script PHP gives copyright message but in TYPO3 backend there is nothing not even in protocol. In setup check I've the last date from my manually bootstrap in TYPO3 but not from the cronjob or from my terminal.

I've enabled cli mode but `php -v` doesn't give any version information or cli hint?

> Configure Command  'configure' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--with-gettext' '--with-mysql' '--with-dom=/usr/include/libxml2/libxml' '--enable-so' '--with-pcre-regex' '--prefix=/usr' '--datadir=/usr/share/php5' '--with-libdir=lib' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/conf.d' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-filter' '--enable-session' '--enable-xml' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-spl' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-cli' '--with-zlib' '--enable-soap' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-ttf' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib' '--with-curl=/usr/local/curl' '--with-readline'

I've also enabled `cgi.check_shebang_line` in my `php.ini` by accident.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the error messages.

Comment: @pgampe: There isn't any error message? Or do you mean when I manually start the thing? I already post my log file and the cron job seems to run!

Comment: Thus it does not return anything at all if you run ``/usr/bin/php /path/to/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler``? Please check the return code with ``echo $?``. Did you check the ``apache`` and ``php`` error log?

Comment: BTW, what ``TYPO3`` version are you using?

Comment: Typo3 is 4.6.9 - 4.7.1. It gives me errors in terminal but I use shell to start the script? It's has shebang for bash? Hmm, I think my php is screwed. I use fastcgi with lighttpd but I can't compile php to run from cli mode? It's working with fastcgi but somehow not in cli mode. My php is 5.3.8 and I have enabled cli killswitch. Setup check is fine cli_backend user is find.

Comment: So please post the errors you get in the terminal!

Comment: Yes, sorry. Look at the strange error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `Setup Check` inside the scheduler module to see if scheduler has been triggered.

Comment: No joy. I can manually start the schedule but not in the shell nor from the cron job which seems to run see my log file.

Comment: But the setup check is otherwise OK?

Comment: How you fixed it ?